# Loading Config for a referenced DLL

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I have a windows application that references a DLL which has a WCF client proxy generated from a WSDL.

What I need to do is have the DLL load its dll.config globally so the client proxy can automatically read the endpoint and binding properties (such as in a regular exe.config).

I'm reading in the Config succesfully in the DLL:

```
ClientSection clientSettings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigPath).GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
```

The above approach just obtains the section so I can manually read out the properties and initialize my WCF proxy client with them. What I want to avoid is exactly that, is there a way to globally load the configuration so all endpoint configuration is loaded into the libraries system.serviceModel instance?

Comment: You should duplicate the config in the running app's config.

Comment: ok so no other approach to loading multiple configs and specifcially using them for specific libraries? Only possibility there is to read the data manually?

Comment: Well, you could try putting a reference to another config file. [see this](https://developers.de/blogs/bahro/archive/2016/02/08/using-external-config-files-in-net-applications.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder, that looks like a good solution here, please post it and i'll mark it the answer.